# I'm unable to findFirstByAttribute in MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

In the documentation of MagicalRecords it is given that

> If you have a unique way of retrieving a single object from your data
> store you should do this

`Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"FirstName" withValue:@"Forrest"];`

I'm doing this

```
DX *foundDX = [DX MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"code" withValue:cell.DXCodeName];
NSLog(@"Found DX: %@, Cell Code Name is: %@",foundDX,cell.DXCodeName.text);
```

If I know the value is in the entity it still give me

> Found DX: (null), Cell Code Name is: F45

But I have this value already in the DX entity

[image]

So What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for putting this here but I don't have the reputation to comment yet. Have you tried passing in the value cell.DXCodeName.text?

Comment: Yes I'm passing value as `[self.AddEditDX setCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.DXCodeName.text]];`

Comment: Sorry, I meant on this line like this
     DX *foundDX = [DX MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"code" withValue:cell.DXCodeName.text];

Comment: By changing that I'm getting this in NSLog `Found DX: <DX: 0x6000000bb9c0> (entity: FavDX; id: 0xd0000000001c0000 <x-coredata://482D1B45-B37C-4772-973D-E5ABFC8F9483/FavDX/p7> ; data: {
    code = F45;
    descriptions = "Somatoform disorders";
    isFav = 1;
}), Cell Code Name is: F45`

Comment: So now it's finding the core data model that you're looking for